# Does Expo Push Notification tool can work on published app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I just want to publish my app on stores (App Store & Google Play Store). My app is working on React Native project linked to create-react-native-app library.

When I use my app in Expo it is working perfectly, but when I test it on TestFlight(for example) it is not working.
I get the ExponentPushToken of my device but I can't send a push notification.

I hope someone have the answer.

Thanks

Comment: Is the ExponentPushToken == APNS/GCM/FCM device token? If so do you have a developer account from Apple? For FCM/GCM just a Google account with a Firebase/Google project is enough to trigger remote notifications.

Comment: Just wondering.. did this work for you? I'm building an app and would like to know if the notifications with Expo is going to be a problem